# Ruby 2.0 iconv replacement

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I don't know Ruby but want to run an script where:

> D:/Heather/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such  file -- iconv (LoadError)

it works somehow if I comment iconv code but it will be much better if I can recode this part:

```
return Iconv.iconv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', (s + ' ') ).first[0..-2]
```

without `iconv`. Maybe I can use `String#encode` here somehow?

Comment: what are you trying to do? if that we get to know,we can suggest you.

Comment: run this script: https://github.com/purcell/darcs-to-git/blob/master/darcs-to-git (line 157 - iconv usage)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Iconv was deprecated (removed) in 1.9.3.
You can still install it.

Reference Material if you unsure:
https://rvm.io/packages/iconv/

However the suggestion is that you don't and rather use:

```
string.encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
```

[API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)

Comment: "deprecated (removed)" - lol, these two words have completely different meanings.

Comment: [The `Iconv` page on APIdock](https://apidock.com/ruby/Iconv) also says that it's deprecated: "Even if some extentions [sic] of implementation dependent are useful, DON’T USE those extentions [sic] in libraries and scripts to widely distribute. If you want to use those feature, use String#encode."

Answer (score 9):

**String#scrub** can be used since Ruby 2.1.

```
str.scrub(''),
str.scrub{ |bytes| '' }
```

Related question: [Equivalent of Iconv.conv(“UTF-8//IGNORE”,…) in Ruby 1.9.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870636/equivalent-of-iconv-convutf-8-ignore-in-ruby-1-9-x)

Answer (score 8):

If you're not on Ruby 2.1, so can't use `String#scrub` then the following will ignore all parts of the string that aren't correctly UTF-8 encoded.

```
string.encode('UTF-16', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').encode('UTF-8')
```

The encode method does almost exactly what you want, but with the caveat that encode doesn't do anything if it thinks the string is already UTF-8.  So you need to change encodings, going via an encoding that can still encode the full set of unicode characters that UTF-8 can encode.  (If you don't you'll corrupt any characters that aren't in that encoding - 7bit ASCII would be a really bad choice!)

Answer (score 0):

I have not had luck with the various approaches using a one line string.encode by itself

But I wrote a backfill that implements String#scrub in MRI pre 2.1, or other rubies that do not have it.

https://github.com/jrochkind/scrub_rb