# Deploy Rails 2.3.16 application on Heroku, try to migrate database, rake aborted! cannot load such file -- iconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy a copy of a Rails 2.3.16 application on Heroku. I pushed the application, and added a PostgreSQL database.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
cannot load such file --iconv
```

Apparently all new applications will run in ruby 2.0.0, and I have been having a lot of trouble managing versions recently. The old applications run in whatever version they were, which is 1.9.2. Maybe that is related. I looked for a long time, and found things such as:

[Ruby 2.0 iconv replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032241/ruby-2-0-iconv-replacement)
[in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829886/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-iconv-loaderror)

I tried `gem install iconv`

This site doesn't help, or maybe I don't understand what to do:

https://rvm.io/packages/iconv

`rvm autolibs rvm_pkg` did nothing. `rvm autolibs enable` didn't help.

This site seemed to say something completely different even though it linked to https://rvm.io/packages/iconv:

http://bullrico.com/2012/09/04/cannot-load-such-file-iconv/

I did:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2-p290 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

At least 2 things failed in that, and iconv issue is not resolved:

```
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/RedApple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/Users/RedApple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global:/Users/RedApple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/Users/RedApple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global GEM_HOME=/Users/RedApple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290 /Users/RedApple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -d /Users/RedApple/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.4/setup.rb',
please read /Users/RedApple/.rvm/log/1379705294_ruby-1.9.2-p290/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.

Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.2-p290 /Users/RedApple/.rvm/scripts/gemsets pristine',
please read /Users/RedApple/.rvm/log/1379705294_ruby-1.9.2-p290/gemset.pristine-ruby-1.9.2-p290.log

heroku run rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- iconv
```

I don't have time to reprogram the 2.3.16 application into 3 or 4 if that is required. I don't even know what iconv is. What is the easiest way to get rid of this error?

Edit:

I put this in the Gemfile and redeployed:

```
ruby '1.9.2'
```

I don't know if it is progress, but now a new error:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --trace

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
bad URI(is not URI?): 
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:156:in `split'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:174:in `parse'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:628:in `parse'
/app/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `block in load_application_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/app/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Edit:

I didn't read the error message thoroughly, and missed this line:

```
/app/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I commented out these lines, since I don't need Redis yet:

```
# uri = URI.parse( ENV[ "REDISTOGO_URL" ] )
# REDIS = Redis.new( :host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password )
```

`heroku run rake db:migrate` finally worked.

Comment: Did you have to have a Gemfile for this?

Answer (score 2):

All of that, and it seems the main problem was solved by adding this line to the Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.2'
```

Lesson learned: If you have an old application that needs to be redeployed for some other purpose on Heroku, you need to specify the ruby version in the Gemfile.