# Cloud9/Heroku - Error H10 App Crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9

Trying to deploy in Heroku, but keep getting Error H10. Besides proper deployment, and running migrations against Heroku, I have tried so far:

- Heroku restart
- Scale down and up again dynos
- Reset db

Here Heroku logs:

```
016-10-24T16:17:44.440699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T16:17:44.451681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T16:17:45.767015+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=typo-cereal.herokuapp.com request_id=6d820278-866f-457b-a033-276068c3b5cb fwd="85.230.142.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T16:17:46.206522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=typo-cereal.herokuapp.com request_id=e3e84db9-96d7-4327-a579-86f3111ea68c fwd="85.230.142.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here rails console:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1508:in `path': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)
        from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1508:in `block in fu_list'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1508:in `map'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1508:in `fu_list'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1127:in `touch'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `touch'
        from /app/app/controllers/admin/categories_controller.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:350:in `require_or_load'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `depend_on'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

App is working fine 'locally' (Cloud9 server). Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032241/ruby-2-0-iconv-replacement   You can see the error is that iconv is deprecated from your logs

Comment: It says 'will be deprecated', not that is deprecated already. I thought the problem was the 'can't convert Hash into String' from fileutils.rb (and I can't find anything about googling)